# Specifiy Nexus repository path at one place

Tags: maven, nexus

At the moment, I need to specify the path of Nexus both in the settings.xml (for building with Maven) and in a parent pom (for deploying with Maven). Is there a way to put this information into just *one* place?

Comment: a property in an active by default profile of the settings file, used both in settings and parent pom? Not sure it will work in settings file though, as placeholder, but at least you would have it in only one file.

Answer (score 0):

In your topmost POM, specify maven deploy plugin version 2.8 or above.
Then in your settings.xml specify

```
<profile>
   <id>nexus</id>
   <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
   </activation>                
   <properties>
      <altSnapshotDeploymentRepository>id::layout::url</altSnapshotDeploymentRepository>    
      <altReleaseDeploymentRepository>id::layout::url</altReleaseDeploymentRepository>
...
```

where id is the same id as given in the (settings.xml) definition of your server (for credentials):

```
<server>
   <id>id</id>
   <username>usr</username>
   <password>pass</password>
</server>
```

layout is default (except if you are using maven 1)

url is the place where you want to upload to (your remote repo).

This eliminates the need to specify the deployment repo inside the project's POM.